# How are most Node applications started?

Tags: node.js

I know to start my Node app I type in the Win shell, node app.js.

But this is obviously not how a webhost would maintain a Node webserver (ie what happens if there is a power outage, a Node exception, etc).

I see things like Forever and running Node as a Windows service, but I feel like the creator of Node must have had a different idea? Something like Apache is installed as a Windows Service so that it runs even if the server reboots - what is the correct method of doing this for Node? I don't like the idea of introducing *another* piece of software just to keep the server going.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, Forever and a cron job that starts it after downtime is the usual way it's done, running behind something like NGINX.

Comment: I'm using Forever that is started in a computer startup script for my node server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that many systems do not do that. For instance MongoDB doesn't even run like that on windows.

The best solution I have found is this https://nssm.cc/

Also you have to consider even on Linux you need to run something like upstart to keep node programs running when you close the console.